Rust variable does not live long enough
Cannot populate a vector in rust using using the code below:
Code:
fn main() {
    let mut list: Vec<&String> = vec![];

    // generate data for processing
    for i in 0..=10 {
        let x = String::from(format!("<name>: {i}")).to_owned();
        list.push(&x);
    }
}

Error:
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:7:19
  |
6 |         let x = String::from(format!("<name>: {i}")).to_owned();
  |             - binding `x` declared here
7 |         list.push(&x);
  |         ----      ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
  |         |
  |         borrow later used here
8 |     }
  |     - `x` dropped here while still borrowed


Just remove & from &x and Vec<&String>.

String::from(format!("{i}")).to_owned() turns i to a String thrice format!("{i}") is all you need.
